# LinkedIn - Basic profile API access issues

Tags: linkedin-api

We are integrating the Linkedin Oauth into our software and would like to retrieve the “vanityname” value from the user account in order to display it in our UI (so the user knows which linkedin account they connected to).

Currently the vanityname seems to be only available for "Basic" profile, but our App only has access to "Lite". We looked everywhere but cannot find a way to request this permission specifically, or request access to “Basic” profile info;

Could you let me know how/where to apply for this permission? I am happy to provide the full usecase and flow of course.